# List index out of range errors

Tags: python, indexing

I'm very new to Python only been digging around in it for about a month now. I've been trying to figure out this code for awhile now and can't figure out what the issue is. I've tried to hardcore the values and I still get the errors. A little program backstory. This program will essentially look at a file containing a list of numbers, it will then let the user pick the folder to search through, and look through several files for the list of numbers provided. First it looks for the header record, then looks to a certain position to see if the numbers match, then copies the remaining rows over to a new file. The troubled code is that of when the loop is supposed to exit ie it's not longer an order.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here:

```
    def read_pos():
    with open(os.path.realpath(BrowsePath.get())) as PONumbers:
        PO = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(os.path.realpath(BrowsePath.get()))] #isolates list of POs
        ponum_count = sum(1 for line in open(os.path.realpath(BrowsePath.get()))) #gets count of PO numbers

        while ponum_count > 0:
            global ponum
            print(PO[ponum])

            fs = 0
            files = os.listdir(SearchPath.get()) #gets list of files
            file_count = len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(SearchPath.get()),'*.*')) #gets count of files


            while file_count > 0:

                with open(os.path.join(SearchPath.get(),files[fs]),'r') as content_file:
                    po_line = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(SearchPath.get(),files[fs])))] #isolates each file
                    line_count = sum(1 for line in open(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(SearchPath.get(),files[fs])))) #gets count of lines in PO File
                    po1 = 0

                    while po1 < line_count: 
                        if po_line[po1][:2] == "10":
                            if po_line[po1][73:90].strip() == PO[ponum]:
                                filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SearchPath.get(),"Results.txt"))
                                NewPOFlag = "N"

                                with open(filename,'a+') as file:
                                    file.write(po_line[po1] + '\n')
                                    print(po_line[po1])     


                                #AREA I'M HAVING TROUPBLE WITH
                                while NewPOFlag == "N":
                                    po1 +=1     
                                    if (po_line[po1][:2] == "10") | (po_line[po1] == '\n'):
                                        NewPOFlag = "Y"
                                    else:
                                        with open(filename,'a+') as file:
                                            file.write(po_line[po1] + '\n')
                                            print(po_line[po1]) 


                            #line_count = line_count - 1



                        #po1 +=1



                print(files[fs])
                fs +=1
                file_count = file_count - 1

            ponum +=1
            ponum_count = ponum_count - 1
```

Here's my traceback results:

```
File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PythonTesting\FindPOs.py", line 124, in read_pos
if (po_line[po1][:2] == "10") | (po_line[po1] == '\n'):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you please include the traceback so that we can see the line that causes the error? This code is quite heavily nested, it's not easy to follow what's happening at each stage.

Comment: My apologies see below:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PythonTesting\FindPOs.py", line 124, in read_pos
    if (po_line[po1][:2] == "10") | (po_line[po1] == '\n'):
IndexError: list index out of range


I realize I should have created separate functions, so the nesting is my rookie mistake.

Comment: Please edit your traceback into the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, updated!

Comment: my guess in `if (po_line[po1][:2] == "10") | (po_line[po1] == '\n'):`, the `po1` value exceeds `line_count`

Comment: That's what I thought to, but the file I'm creating has all the data in one of the files and in printing the values of the data, i see line_count = 47 and po1 = 0

Comment: [Catch the Exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) with a try/except block around that line and in the except suite print out relevant variables like ```po_line```, and ```po1```,  That should give you a starting point.